# How to compile a .tex file to a text file (not a PDF format)?

Tags: pdftex, output, text-only

A lot of job applications ask for a plain text version of a resume. My resume is in LaTeX so it's no problem producing a nice PDF, but copying and pasting from the PDF into notepad, for example, is horrible. Is there a command that TeXworks can do (or `pdflatex` in Ubuntu) that can output some representation of .tex in a text file (ideally preserving things like spacing)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.